# Swift How can i make custom cell for the collection of jsqmessageViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

i wold like to get explanation on how to do it, 
what classes to subclass .
what to override and so on.
for the  of jsqmessageViewcontroller framework

for example outgoing cell , how to build my out layout and labels

any help will be appreciate

and yes i did search for it didn't find a lot info about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a custom cell or xib and then when implementing the JSQ framework just use your custom cell in the

`override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     //Configure your cell here
return //yourCustomCell
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the series which you can follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1