# Swift - JSQMessagesViewController - cell custom

Tags: swift, custom-cell, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I understood from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652255/swift-how-can-i-make-custom-cell-for-the-collection-of-jsqmessageviewcontroller) that you can customise the cell of the JSQMessagesViewController library by overriding this method:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,  cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 //Configure your cell here
return //yourCustomCell
}
```

Is there a possibility to get a sample code to understand how to implement the actual customisation including the subclass of the JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell?

As an example, I would like to add a label included at the bottom of the message bubble showing the time the message has been sent.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have created a custom cell class as follow:

```
class MyCustomCell: JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell {

    var textLabel: UILabel

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        self.textLabel = UILabel(frame:  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height/3))
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.smallSystemFontSize())
        self.textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        contentView.addSubview(self.textLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

The custom cell is made programmatically without any xib file.

So in my JSQMessagesViewController, I have to declare it as follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView!.registerClass(MyCustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell")
}
```

And then, I'm able to override the cellForItemAtIndexPath method as follow:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
    return cell
}
```

The issue is that I cannot see the messages and previous settings anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Anyone could help me to get to the right direction? How MyCustomCell can keep all the behaviour and properties of the parent? Seems I have an issue with the init of the super class...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way I managed to make it:

1- Create two sub-classes:

- JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing

  ```
  import UIKit
  import JSQMessagesViewController

  class messageViewOutgoing: JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing {

      @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)        
      }
  }
  ```
- JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming

  ```
  import UIKit
  import JSQMessagesViewController

  class messageViewIncoming: JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming {

      @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)        
      }
  }
  ```

2- Create two xib files with names related to the two subclasses above. For each file, add the custom class related in the File's owner Placeholder.

3- Copy/paste the xib templates of each related classes from the JSQMessagesViewController library stored in the Resources folder and add your custom label into it.

4- Link the custom labels to your new subclasses above

5- Override the following function

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let message = self.messages[indexPath.item]

    if message.senderId == self.senderId {

        let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! messageViewOutgoing

        cell.timeLabel.text = localHourFormatter.stringFromDate(message.date)

        return cell

    } else {

        let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! messageViewIncoming

        cell.timeLabel.text = localHourFormatter.stringFromDate(message.date)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Now the label is displayed in the bubble.

Still some work to do to adapt the size of the bubble for a proper display but this is not the purpose of this question.

Let me know if any comment/question.

Comment: Make all what you described here, but still get crash in cellForRowAtIndexPath "Could not cast value of type 'JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing' (0x10b5f3538) to 'myApp.OutgoingMessageCell' (0x108cf9690)." Any ideas?

Comment: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class

Comment: Hi guys sorry for not responding. Difficult to help with the feedback you give. I gave up on this library and moved to react native for mobile development anyway. I'll try to find the project where I made it work and share it on github. Keep you posted.

Comment: Please follow this link, if you guys still stuck with the above error.. https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1809

Comment: I am getting error  in the line   cell =  super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)  as! messageViewOutgoing   . Error is  Could not cast value of type 'JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing' to 'messageViewOutgoing'    . hat's wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

Go to xcode make a new file then choose **Cocoa Touch class** and in subclass list choose

**UICollectionViewCell** and put your custom cell name like

**customCellUICollectionViewCell.swift**

After that go **Mainstoryboard**  and drag a new collection cell to your view

Select your cell and in the right side menu in xcode choose

**Show the identity inspector**

and in Custom class type your custom class name

**customCellUICollectionViewCell.swift**

last thing in your collection view

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,  cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCellUICollectionViewCell
return cell
}
```

Comment: I cannot drag a new collection cell. The whole collectionView is created by the library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are just not setting the text of you custom cell. I would also guard for safety

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,  cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell else {
    print("Could not get my custom cell")
    return UICollectionViewCell()
  }

  let message = messages[indexPath.row] // or what ever your messages are called

  let cell.mainLabel.text = message.text

  return cell
}
```

Comment: how to delete cell with image in jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I got error: Can't cast from messageViewOutgoing to JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming @sbkl. Did you get this error, because we can't cast from parent type to child type?